# Add a title to leaflet layers control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Does anyone have a method for adding a title to a leaflet layers control? Just a line of text, for example "Available layers." Ideally I'd like to add a link to the text as well.

I thought it would be simple, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I tried methods similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078310/how-can-i-style-layer-control-in-leaflet-js) (radio button/checkbox remains after adding "dummy" layer) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906118/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-html-to-leaflet-layer-groups-and-layers-control) (adds div to end of layers, seems more complex than my needs). Unfortunately with my experience level, I haven't been able to connect the dots. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Input Elements in Layer Control are present under

> .leaflet-control-layers-overlays

`$(".leaflet-control-layers-overlays").prepend("<label>Available layers</label>");`
You can also assign a class and add some styling on this. This is not good solution but hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

#Leaflet1.7
Here is the vanilla JS minimal solution.

```
// 0. Your's WMS layers:      
var fooLayers = {
      "Aaa" : ign_ari,
      "Bbb" : ign_cri,
      "Ccc" : ign_grvi
};

// 1. start with Control
var fooLegend = L.control({position: 'topleft'});

fooLegend.onAdd = function () {
      var div = L.DomUtil.create('div');
      // here is Your part:
      div.innerHTML = '<span class='your-class'>Your Title Text</span>';
      return div;
};
fooLegend.addTo(map);

var fooCtrl = L.control.layers(fooLayers, null,
              {collapsed : false, position: 'topleft'})
              .addTo(map);

//
// Nothing unusual, until now:
var fooCtrlDiv = fooCtrl.getContainer();
fooCtrlDiv.insertBefore(fooLegend.getContainer(), fooCtrlDiv.firstChild);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Looking for a solution where it works with `collapsed: true` now :)

Answer (score 2):

Leaflet 1.7: Addition to @Mruk's answer: If you want to use `collapsed: true`, then you have to dig a little bit deeper in the DOM tree:

```
const fooCtrlDiv = fooCtrl.getContainer();

fooCtrlDiv
  .querySelector('.leaflet-control-layers-list')
  .insertBefore(
    fooLegend.getContainer(),
    layerControlDiv.querySelector('.leaflet-control-layers-list').firstChild
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a title attribute to the control. Here's an obviously incomplete snippet from a current project:

```
// Add settings button
var atlasMapSettings = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'topleft' 
  },
  onAdd: function (map) {
    var control = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control leaflet-control-custom atlas-settings-control closed');
    var icon    = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'fa fa-gear closed', control);
    var content = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'control-content empty', control);

    $(icon).attr('title', 'Map settings');
```

Comment: It looks like the braces aren't matching up? I'm not sure where the first one should close.

Comment: It's a partial example that depends on extending a control object, not just adding a basic control. (Which I realize is much more complicated, and maybe not super helpful here, on second thought.)

More about custom controls:

http://odoe.net/blog/custom-leaflet-control/