# Add title to layers control box in Leaflet using R

Tags: r, leaflet

I am looking to add a title to the layer control box along the lines of "Available layers".

My search has lead me to only one relevant result:

- [Exact same question using JS.  Unclear how to translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152868/add-a-title-to-leaflet-layers-control?rq=1)

My code:

```
map %>% leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "CartoDB") %>%
  # Group 1 Polygons
  addPolygons(data = map[!is.na(map$var),] ,weight =1, 
              color = ~g1_pal(g1), fillOpacity = .6,
              group = "Group 1",
              # add labels
              label = ~labels,
              # highlight polygons on hover
              highlight = highlightOptions(weight = 5, color = "white",
                                           bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
  # Group 2
  addPolygons(data = map[!is.na(map$var2),], weight =1, 
              color = ~g2_pal(g2), fillOpacity = .6,
              group = "Group 2",
              # add labels that display mean income
              label = ~labels2,
              # highlight polygons on hover
              highlight = highlightOptions(weight = 5, color = "white",
                                           bringToFront = TRUE)) %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Group 1", "Group 2"), 
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed=F, 
                                                  # Series of attempts 
                                                  label = "Layers",
                                                  title = "Layers"))
```

Neither of these attempts worked.  It does appear from the link above that there is an attribute that can be accessed but I am unsure of how to reference it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to do this (that I'm aware of) is to use `htmlwidgets::onRender` to add your Javascript to the map upon rendering. This is described in the [last section at the bottom of the last page in the docs](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/morefeatures.html), so it's easy to miss!

Here's an example that implements the Javascript that Saurabh Yadav described in his answer to the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152868/add-a-title-to-leaflet-layers-control?rq=1). You simply add the Javascript function to the end of the `leaflet()` piped call:

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = "MyImaginaryLine",
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
    htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function() {
            $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays').prepend('<label style=\"text-align:center\">My Epic Title</label>');
        }
    ")
```

[image: output]

Comment: For baseGroups you need `.leaflet-control-layers-list` instead of `.leaflet-control-layers-overlays`

Comment: Seems like  `.leaflet-control-layers-base'` might be the better options for elements assigned to the baseGroups parameter. 

The `.leaflet-control-layers-list` is the container that holds the base and overlay elements. 
So the label would sit about the baseGroups only because those are written first within the list element.