# How to add a tooltip above `addPulseMarkers` in Leaflet?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I can't find any documentation on how to add a tooltip with addPulseMarkers above the Layer Control (using leaflet.extras). See below for an example of what I'd aiming to do.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)



ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(quakes) %>%
    addPulseMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, 
                      icon = makePulseIcon(color = "blue", heartbeat = 2),
                      group = "I want a tooltip on hover above this that says, 'Nice'") %>%
      addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = c("I want a tooltip on hover above this that says, 'Nice'"), 
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
      )
      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm looking for the "Nice" to be above the legend in the top right.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)



ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(quakes) %>%
      addPulseMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, 
                      icon = makePulseIcon(color = "blue", heartbeat = 2),
                      group = "I want a tooltip on hover above this that says, 'Nice'") %>%
      addLayersControl(
        overlayGroups = c("I want a tooltip on hover above this that says, 'Nice'"), 
        options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
      ) %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender("
        function() {
            $('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays').prepend('<label style=\"text-align:center\">Nice</label>');
        }
    ")
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It borrows from: [Add title to layers control box in Leaflet using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413381/add-title-to-layers-control-box-in-leaflet-using-r)

Comment: That's close. Thanks. But I'd ideally like hover text or a "tooltip"...something like https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_hover2.